# Choosing options conditionally for reusable Select Component

Tags: reactjs, html-select, react-select

I'm using react-select and am creating a reusable Select Component that will conditionally choose which options list to render in the proper `select` element by checking the `name` attribute.

When I code it using the `select` html, `options` renders fine.  I've added an options element to have a placeholder for the list.
This works, but I would also like to try creating it with `react-select`
The problem is, the options arent rendering, but the correct list chosen after the conditional is met shows when I `console.log`.

Any thoughts as to the error I'm making when trying with `react-select`?

The two imported data lists are, one is an object of key, value pairs and the 2nd is an array of single values.

Code as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {countriesData1} from '../data/countries-data.js';
import {stateData3} from '../data/states-data.js';

class SelectComp extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    selectCountry: PropTypes.string,
    handleChange: PropTypes.func
  }

  state = {
      countryList: countriesData1,
      stateList: stateData3,
    }
  
  render() {
    const {stateList, countryList} = this.state;

    const optionsCountry = Object.entries(countryList).map((entry, _) => {
      let key = entry[0]
      let value = entry[1]
      return <option key={key}
                     value={value}>
                       {value}
              </option>
     });

    const optionsState = stateList.map(data => {
      return <option key={data}
              value={data}>
                {data}
             </option>
    });

    let options;
    if(this.props.name === "Country") {
      options = optionsCountry;
    } else {
      options = optionsState;
    }
   
    return (
      <div>
        <Select name={`${this.props.name}`} 
              className={`select-options select-${this.props.name}`}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
              placeholder= {this.props.name === "Country" ? "Select Country" : "Select State"}
              options={options}
              />  

        <select name={`${this.props.name}`} 
                className={ `select-options select-${this.props.name}` }
                onChange={this.props.handleChange}>
                <option value=""
                        hidden> Select {this.props.name}</option>
                   {options}     
               {options} 
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SelectComp;
```

Thank you,
Lee

Comment: `react-select` does not accept `<option>` elements, it accepts objects in the form `{ value: 'some_value', label: 'The label'}`

Comment: Then would an imported data file that is an array of objects and an array of data need to be reformatted to be able to use it for options in ```react-select```?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you typically setup `react-select`:

```
const options = [{
    value: '1',
    label: 'Option 1'
}, {
    value: '2',
    label: 'Option 2'
}]

 return <Select name="select-name" 
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="placeholder"
          options={options}
          />
```

Given an API, e.g. `books` you could map the results into options like so:

```
const options = books.map(book => ({ value: book.id, label: book.title })
```